# Как в angular tranlate узнать текущий язык?

Tags: angularjs, локализация

[angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/)
Незнаю типа `$translateProvider.getCurrentLanguage`?

Comment: добавь ссылку на _angular tranlate_ который используешь

Comment: $translate.use()

Comment: @L.Vadim, напишите как ответ к комменту, прим как правильное решение, действительно, оказывается так просто

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это просто. Испульзуем :

```
$translate.use()
```

Comment: а вот ссылка на справку: [use](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate#methods_use) - _If no or a falsy key is given it returns the currently used language key. The returned string will be undefined if setting up $translate hasn't finished._

Comment: @Grundy, пытался я RTFM в доки но у меня плохо с английским, а там еще все в кучу как-то ИМХО. тяжело воспринимать. Ну и ожидал чего-то типа "current lang"